# How to enable/disable DNS Settings from mobileconfig using command line?

Tags: network, command-line, dns

I'm using DOH from https://github.com/paulmillr/encrypted-dns.
This installs a mobile config profile.
I can enable and disable the DNS Settings by going into `Network`, then `Filters` (image reference below).

Is there any way to toggle this via command line?

I've tried `networksetup`:

```
# networksetup -getdnsservers Wi-Fi
There aren't any DNS Servers set on Wi-Fi.
```

Thanks.

[image: macos network filters]

Comment: May be a stupid question, but are you connected via Ethernet or WiFi?

Comment: Try `networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA` this will set your DNS for your particular interface.

Comment: @nohillside I'm connected via Wi-Fi.

Comment: @Allan I need to set DNS-over-HTTPS or DNS-over-TLS instead of normal DNS address.

Comment: I think this is a userprofile.  Try the command `networksetup -listalluserprofiles` and let me know if you see the profile you created.

Comment: @Allan trying `networksetup -listalluserprofiles` returns `** Error: This command is no longer supported.`
While I'm at it, I noticed and tried `networksetup -enableuserprofile`, also returning the same error.

Comment: Ok…try `networksetup -listallnetworkservices` and see this service shows up.

Comment: @Allan It shows `Wi-Fi` and `Thunderbolt Bridge`.

Comment: Let’s try `networksetup -listloginprofiles W-Fi`.  I’m operating off my iPad at the moment so I can’t  test these out for you.

Comment: @Allan It returns `** Error: This command is no longer supported.`. Looks like macOS Ventura 13.2.1 stop supporting bunch of networksetup features. I'm sorry you had to help me from the iPad, thanks.

Comment: No worries.  It frustrates me that I can’t get you pointed in the right direction